# Error while creating custom post type template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I create custom post type for works its content displayed using `single.php` but not dispalyed use `single-dp_work.php`

This is my `function.php` code it use to register custom post type 'work'

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function create_posttype() { 
    register_post_type('dp_work', array(
        'labels' => array( 
            'name' => __( 'Work' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Work' ), 
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Work' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Work' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Work' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Work' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Work' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Work' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No books found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Work' )
        ),
        'public' => true, 
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'works')
    )); 
}
```

Comment: try 'name' => __( 'Works' )  instead of 'name' => __( 'Work' )

Comment: @webeno , i try that one but not got.

Comment: i wasn't the one who suggested that, it was @Yatendra... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush rewrite rules before this permalink work

```
function my_rewrite_flush() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

Follow this 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation